# Finding the 1st and 2nd derivatives of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an oscillatory function f(ф, ф'), and I want to differentiate it. function like this:

```
df(ф, ф')/dф | ф, ф'= 0
df(ф, ф')/dф' | ф, ф'= 0
d^2f(ф, ф')/dф^2 | ф, ф'= 0
d^2f(ф, ф')/dф'^2 | ф, ф'=0
df(ф, ф')/dфdф' | ф, ф'=0
```

How can I write the above expressions in the Wolfram Language?

Comment: Have a look at [D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html?q=D).

Comment: In your equations is `\[Phi]'` intended to symbolize a derivative or is it a second variable?

Answer (score 2):

In mathematica the tick mark applied to `ϕ'` represents the derivative so you need to use a different symbol.

I will simply use `x` and `y` in the examples below.

Here is what you are looking for using a general function as well as an example function, `x^2 + y2`.

The derivative with respect to `x` evaluated at `y=0`.

```
D[f[x, y], x] /. y -> 0
D[x^2 + y^2, x] /. y -> 0
```

The derivative with respect to `y` evaluated to `y=0`

```
D[f[x, y], y] /. y -> 0
D[x^2 + y^2, y] /. y -> 0
```

The second derivative with respect to `x` evaluated at `y=0`.

```
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] /. y -> 0
D[x^2 + y^2, {x, 2}] /. y -> 0
```

The derivative with respect to `x` and then `y` evaluated at `y=0`

```
D[f[x, y], x, y] /. y -> 0
D[x^2 + y^2, x, y] /. y -> 0
```

In all of these examples the first term evaluates the derivative.

The expression `/. y -> 0` means take the expression on the left and replace `y` with `0`. This effectively evaluates the expression at `y=0`.

Comment: Thanks. Also the both x (or ф in my example) and y (ф') must be:
| ф=0 , ф'=0
I think the final function looks like this:
D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] /. y -> 0 /. x->0

Comment: Furthermore with y->0 and x->0 i get the infinite expression encountered error. How can i display the maximal result (with 1/0, yep) with this error?

Comment: If you are getting an expression with an error message "Infinite expression 1/0 enountered" that implies you are using a particular function `f`. You should ask a separate question and include your function in that question.

Answer (score 2):

Say your function is:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
```

Then, you can use Derivative:

```
Derivative[1,0][f][0,0]
Derivative[0,1][f][0,0]
Derivative[2,0][f][0,0]
Derivative[1,1][f][0,0]
Derivative[0,2][f][0,0]
```

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 0